Mapping PWM chip and channel in c# to PWM, Function and/or ALT
I'm following the instructions in this document in order to get hardware PWM working.
I added this line to my /boot/firmware/config.txt
dtoverlay=pwm,pin=18,func=2

According to the docs this should enable PWM on GPIO18 wich maps to the hardware Pin12 of my RaspberryPi 4.
The frustrating thing is that c# library System.Device.Pwm.PwmChannel.Create(chip, channel) takes chip and channel parameters, but how to map these to whatever is configured seems to be undocumented.
How exactly does one map chip and channel to the columns PWM, Function and/or Alt.
I was assuming that chip=PWM and channel=Function however I guess the assumption must be wrong due to persistent errors:

System.ArgumentException: The chip number 0 is invalid or is not enabled.


The documentation seems to be inconsistent with GPIO/Logic/Physical Pin numberings or I'm getting it wrong. It also appears to be different on different pi models. Any way, I needed pin=12,func=4 instead of pin=18,func=2 here's a working setup for the Pi4:
In /boot/firmware/config.txt add the line:
dtoverlay=pwm,pin=12,func=4

in code:
public class PwmClass
{
    private readonly PwmChannel _pwm = PwmChannel.Create(0, 0);

    public void SetPwm(double value)
    {
        if (value > 1)
            value = 1;
        else if (value < 0)
            value = 0;

        _pwm.DutyCycle = value;

        if (value > 0)
            _pwm.Start();
        else
            _pwm.Stop();
    }
}

